# How to redirect a subdomain to an other site

Tags: redirect, dns, host

I have this website www.ipsum.nl. And a subdomain as lorum.ipsum.nl.
I have also an other website www.othersite.com.

How do I let lorum.ipsum.nl redirect to www.othersite.com without having to load an other page such as 'index.html'?

Comment: You didnt even mention what web server you are using. Apache? Nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file:

```
RewriteEngine on  
Redirect 301 http://lorum.ipsum.nl http://www.othersite.com
```

or you can use regular expressions with the RewriteEngine to match subdomains.